# Cannot change passphrase

Tags: timer-jobs, timer-service

I cannot change my passphrase.

Here is my Powershell commands

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> $passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Mypassphrase1" -asPlainText  -force
PS C:\Users\myuser> Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -Confirm

cmdlet Set-SPPassPhrase at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ConfirmPassPhrase: *************

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Set-SPPassPhrase" on Target "SPPassPhrase".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):A
Set-SPPassPhrase : Error deploying administration application pool
credentials. Another deployment may be active. An object of the type
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPMasterPassphraseDeploymentJobDefinition
named "job-admin-passphrase-change" already exists under the parent
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerService named "SPTimerV4".  Rename
your object or delete the existing object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -Confirm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etSetPassPhrase:
   SPCmdletSetPassPhrase) [Set-SPPassPhrase], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetPassPhrase
```

I have tried to clean the cache as suggested in other posts. 
And after cleaning the cache I can apparently set the passphrase.
But the job doesn't execute even if the timer service is running. 
Besides, If I try this code

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> $job = Get-sptimerjob job-admin-passphrase-change
PS C:\Users\myuser> $job

Name                 Schedule             Last Run
----                 --------             --------
job-admin-passphr...                      8/5/2015 6:11:22 AM
```

I see the job is still there. And if I try to reset the passphrase once again I get the initial error named "job-admin-passphrase-change" already exists under the parent .

Is there anything I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a stupid answer, but I had this exact problem once before and I restarted the SharePoint Timer Service and reran the job, and the problem went away.

Comment: thanks, but I have already tried that